# Is there a keyboard shortcut to silence JAWS?

Tags: accessibility, tools, jaws

I'm testing a web application's accessibility with JAWS 15. I don't want JAWS to keep reading when I'm not actively testing something so I have to keep shutting the application down and starting it back up again.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle JAWS on and off? I guess I could just use the mute button on my keyboard, but that doesn't stop JAWS from trying to keep up with what I'm doing and wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: Is there a UX question in here? This question doesn't sound on topic.

Comment: It's about accessibility. Okay, it's about accessibility *testing*. If User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers aren't interested in that topic, who is?

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney see this [meta discussion](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/should-tool-related-questions-be-on-topic) related to tools.  If you have an opinion on whether the UX.SE site should be only about user experience in the academic sense and not be at all concerned with how it is applied through process or tools, that thread is a good place to share it.

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the link. It won't hurt my feelings if this question is closed or deleted.

Comment: JAWS has a text output as well, if I remember correctly, specifically for debugging.

Comment: You should migrate your question to superuser.com

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney fair enough! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, this isn't a UX question because you're asking about how to use a Tool not about the process or psychology, or study of accessibility testing.

A basic Google search has revealed what you are likely looking for:

http://www.freedomscientific.com/doccenter/archives/training/JAWSKeystrokes.htm

**Toggle Speech On or Off**

INSERT+SPACEBAR, S

Comment: Thank you. I did some Googling and searched the help docs before asking and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Ironically I just copied the statement from you into google: "keyboard shortcut to toggle jaws on and off" :)

Comment: I actually landed on that page and overlooked the answer while skimming. Next time someone is looking for the same information hopefully they'll land on *this* page where the answer is staring them in the face.

Comment: I'm using JAWS 18, and INSERT+SPACEBAR, S did not turn JAWS off. INSERT+SPACEBAR, S can only stop current speech like Ctrl key.